# Mouse click fails and only Ctrl Alt Del brings back the functionality

Tags: windows-10, mouse, hardware-failure

I've had this issue for 2 months. I've tried a number of things but the issue still persists. The problem is that my mouse randomly don't drag, left click, right click or double click. In this situation my mouse can move and even hover (you can see its tooltip), but clicking and the other functionality won't work. So I have two choices:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and click on task manager and everything will be fine for some moment. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> won't work in this situation).
2. I have to use keyboard or touch it and after that may be my mouse functionality will back (sometimes won't).

I have to add this, when I type something, the cursor changes the line randomly.

What I have done:

- I use clean boot or `sfc/scannow` and the other commands but nothing found.
- I updated my Windows to the latest version and I used Driver Easy to update all my drivers.
- I reinstalled windows 10 from Microsoft cloud with deep format, but in the beginning of the installation I couldn't click some buttons and I had to touch the laptop or use the keyboard.
- This issue is not just for Windows 10; I tried Ubuntu 22.04 and I
  faced with this problem.
- After windows installation, I didn't install any programs and it is still fresh and I installed all types of antiviruses such as
  Bitdefender, Kaspersky, ESET NOD32 and even Windows defender. There isn't any viruses.
- I disconnected the laptop's trackpad cable and also keyboard's cable, and I used 3 or 4 other mice with different brands but the problem was existed.

My laptop Specs:

- Laptop name: Vivobook S400ca
- 12G RAM
- 240G SSD

Comment: Can you test this problem when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: In the safe mode I had this problem.

Comment: When you reinstalled Windows from scratch, did you have the problem *before* you used Driver Easy (which should be avoided in any case)?

Comment: Yes, I had the problem even in the windows installation and I could click some of the buttons. After the installation I thought it should be windows update or drivers update, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Good diagnostics! If you tried running Ubuntu 22.04 **from USB**, rather than in Windows WSL, you've confirmed the issue is with hardware. By trying different mice (presumably **wired USB**, rather than wireless), you've confirmed that it's not the mouse at fault. That leaves only the internal Vivobook hardware, or a hub, if the mouse is plugged into one.  Since you've even unplugged the trackpad and keyboard, perhaps it's an encoder chip on the main board causing the problem, which might require professional repair.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

1.Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

2.Type `control userpasswords2` or `netplwiz` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

3.Click the Advanced tab.

4.Under Secure sign-in, check the Require users to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> checkbox.

5.Click Apply.

6.Restart your computer.

7.Open the same settings again and uncheck the Require users to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> checkbox and follow the steps 5 and 6.

[Source](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/mouse-clicking-not-responding-until-ctrl-alt-delete.356142/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).